# Vulkan Compute dispatch from a child CPU thread

Tags: multithreading, unreal-engine4, vulkan, compute-shader

Can Vulkan Compute dispatch from a child CPU thread, or does it have to dispatch from the main thread? I don't think this is possible to dispatch compute shaders in Unity from child threads and I wanted to find out if it could be done in Unreal Engine.

Comment: I guess Unity does support Vulkan as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "dispatch" and "main thread".

`vkCmdDispatch`, as the "`Cmd`" prefix suggests, puts a command in a command buffer. This can be called on any thread, so long as the `VkCommandBuffer` object will not have other `vkCmd` functions called on it at the same time (typically, you reserve specific command buffers for a single thread). So by one definition, you can "dispatch" compute operations from other threads.

Of course, recording commands in a command buffer doesn't actually *do anything*. Commands only get executed when you queue up those CBs via `vkQueueSubmit`. Like `vkCmdDispatch`, it doesn't matter what thread you call that function on. However, like `vkCmdDispatch`, it *does matter* that multiple threads be prevented from accessing the same `VkQueue` object at the same time.

Now, you don't have to use a single thread for that `VkQueue`; you can lock the `VkQueue` behind some kind of mutex, so that only one thread can own it at a time. And thus, a thread that creates a CB could submit its own work.

However, ignoring the fact that tasks often need to be inserted into the queue in an order (one task might generate some compute data that a graphics task needs to wait on, so the graphics task CB *must* be after the compute CB), there's a bigger problem. `vkQueueSubmit` takes a *long time*. If you look at the function, it can take an arbitrarily large number of CBs to insert, and it has the ability to have multiple batches, with each batch guarded by semaphores and fences for synchronization. As such, you are *strongly* encouraged to make as few `vkQueueSubmit` calls as possible, since each call has a quantity of overhead to it that has nothing to do with how many CBs you are queuing up.

There's even a warning about this in the spec itself.

So the typical way applications are structured is that you farm out tasks to the available CPU threads, and these tasks build command buffers. One particular thread will be anointed as the owner of the queue. That thread may perform some CB building, but once it is done, it will wait for the other tasks to complete and gather up all of the CBs from the other threads. Once gathered, that thread will `vkQueueSubmit` them in appropriate batches.

You could call that thread the "main thread", but Vulkan itself doesn't really care *which* thread "owns" the queue. It certainly doesn't have to be your process's initial  thread.